# IllegalAccessError when I add a library

Tags: android

When I try to add this lib :

```
compile 'com.isupatches:wisefy:1.0.9'
```

I have this error with my app (without using it) :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[GCM]
>                                                    Process: my.app, PID: 7667
>                                                    java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void
>   android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.()' is inaccessible to
>   class 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' (declaration of
>   'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in
>   /data/app/my.app-1/base.apk:classes2.dex)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdL(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at gcm.RegistrationIntentService.onHandleIntent(RegistrationIntentService.java:54)
>                                                        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

This is the line of the problem :

```
 InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
```

I have look the reason of this error and it seem it's because I use a version too old of my play-services.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

But it's working without adding the lib [wisefy](https://github.com/isuPatches/WiseFy/) so how can I isolate this problem (because I don't want to update my library) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `Wisefy`, as it uses `support-v4` too (like `play-services-gcm`), a more recent version of `support-v4` will be used in your project which your old `play-services-gcm` library can not rely on. That's why you get this error.

Comment: What I have to do ? Forced to upgrading `play-services-gcm` ?

Comment: yes, since you need to use `Wisefy`, to have both of them work you have to use an updated version of `gcm`, the best choice is to use the latest one, i.e. one of `10.0.+` versions of it.